# Cannot wrap ItemsPresenter with a DynamicResource

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using `MaterialDesignInXaml` for stylize my application. Said that, I'm using a ListView with a `CollectionViewGroup` for group my items, anyway, in the `GroupStyle` I've this structure:

```
<GroupStyle>
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <DockPanel Height="16.5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name.Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="11.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="11.5" Foreground="Orange" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <Border Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
</GroupStyle>
```

Now the problem is on this line: `<Border Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}">`, if I remove the border all working well, but with the xml above I get this exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Unable to cast objects of type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to type 'System.Windows.Style'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Can not cast objects of type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' on the type 'System.Windows.Style'.

why happen this?

Comment: *Unable to cast objects of type System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush to type System.Windows.Style* is a pretty clear error message. Obviously MaterialDesignPaper is a SolidColorBrush, not a Style. You can't assign it to a Style property.

Comment: @Clemens that's strange 'cause I've assigned it to another collection and it working, now the collection that cause the problem isn't visible on the ui, in particular is loaded later when the user click on the tabitem of that collection. Could be something related to virtualization or similar?

Comment: No idea. I don't know what MaterialDesignPaper actually is. However, *if* it is a Brush, you can't assign it to a Style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaterialDesignPaper is a Brush, not a Style.

Therefore, depending on your requirement, you want something like this:

`<Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}" />`

or

`<Border Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}" />`

All Material Design In XAML Brushes are listed here: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Brush-Names